# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] in file Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 678

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have Laravel installed on Mac using docker. I connecting to it with postman

The method ge returns this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `flights`) in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 678       

    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(752): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;runQueryCallback()
        #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(732): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
        #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(641): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;handleQueryException()
        #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(346): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;run()
        #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2313): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;select()
        #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2301): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder-&gt;runSelect()
        #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2796): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder-&gt;Illuminate\Database\Query\{closure}()
```

Comment: If you have `127.0.0.1` hard-coded as the database location, that's wrong in Docker; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for details on how to connect to a database in a container both managed by Docker Compose.  That's really just a guess, though; it's hard to diagnose this with just the error message and no source code or configuration.

Comment: yes I have the correct connection because I made the migrations and seeds the problems is when I try to access as API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change `localhost` to your computer's IP address.

Comment: Do you mean the hosts file?